# Schema lookup for stored procedure different to tables (bug?)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

If you run the following in sql server...

```
CREATE SCHEMA [cp]
GO

CREATE TABLE [cp].[TestIt](
    [ID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE cp.ProcSub
AS
BEGIN
    Print 'Proc Sub'
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE cp.ProcMain
AS
BEGIN
    Print 'Proc Main'
    EXEC ProcSub
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE cp.ProcMain2
AS
BEGIN
    Print 'Proc Main2'
    SELECT * FROM TestIt
END
GO

exec cp.ProcMain2
GO

exec cp.ProcMain
GO
```

You get the error

> Could not find stored procedure 'ProcSub'

Which makes it impossible to compartmentalize procedures into a schema without hard coding the schema into the execution call. Is this by design or a bug as doing a select on tables looks in the procedures schema first.

If anyone has a work around I'd be interested to hear it, although the idea is that I can give a developer two stored procedures which call each other and can put into whatever schema they like in 'their' database that they can run for the purpose of being a utility that looks at the objects of another given schema in the same database.

I have looked to see if I might be able to get round it with Synonyms but they seem to have the same problem associated with them.

Comment: After you create schema, did you change the user's default schema to cp? During execution the context is taken from user's default schema, which in your case would be still set as dbo, that isd why you are gettign this error. So to resolve either use "exec cp.prodsub" or update user.

Comment: That's the whole point, I don't want to change the default schema for the user. These need to be a distinct set of objects in a different schema that should work in the same way as if they were tables in a different schema.

Comment: ok, if you have a user, lets say Jayesh, that has access to "cp" schema, then you can try EXECUTE AS Jayesh right after the declaration to get away with this problem. But ofcourse you will have to allow impersonation. Talk to you DBA to know more about it and any specific restrictions your DBA has placed before using it . Reference - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, because the default schema is not set for the user calling the procedure.

When schema is not specified in the query, sql server will try the default schema first and then the dbo (if different) schema. So you need to set the default schema or make your procedure creation using fully qualified names.

Check out:

> Beginning with SQL Server 2005, each user has a default schema. The
>   default schema can be set and changed by using the DEFAULT_SCHEMA
>   option of CREATE USER or ALTER USER. If DEFAULT_SCHEMA is left
>   undefined, the database user will have dbo as its default schema.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: If you create two equivalent tables say 'TestIt' with different structure and/or data, one in dbo and one in the cp schema, changing the Exec ProcSub to select * from TestIt will pick up the one in the cp schema first and if that doesn't exist will default to the dbo.TestIt version so whilst a user has a default schema, I don't think this is by design.

Comment: The article you point to also suggests that you should be able to compartmentalize an entire set of objects into a different schema and put different permissions on each object. Having a default schema just says these are the default set of objects you will be using not that you are forced to use those objects or should be required to explicitly state which schema the version is you are using, it should look at the current context surely.

Comment: Well, there is a connect for it back from 2007 with a "won't fix". So the inconsistency between Procedure and Table default schema lookup is known but not changed thus far. 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/272964/using-default-schema-in-stored-procedures So where there indeed is an inconsistency, the methodology of how default schema works for stored procedures is documented as taking the default schema for the user first, and then dbo.

Comment: Also this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d3ccb3a9-1e91-4162-8252-9c60dc0b9e25/default-schema-resolution-doesnt-work-within-stored-procedure?forum=sqldatabaseengine indicates it's by design with procedures due to cache rules. Anyways - fully qualifying is always the best approach to avoid misunderstandings and strange context shift happening.

Comment: The connect you point to is not this issue and is by design selecting from a table in the context it's run. It's saying if you do a select * from table in batch it's using the default users schema whereas if you do a select * from table in a procedure it's using the procedures schema. I'm asking for it to be done the same way for procedures as for tables so this is confirming the point.

Comment: The cache thread you mention again states... 'An object reference in a stored procedure always refers to the same object, as determined by the owner of the stored proceedure. The user's default schema has no importance.' This again is the point. In my scenario the default schema is dbo, both procedure schemas are cp, I would expect the default schema to have 'no importance' and the cp version to be picked up each time, but it's not it's looking for the default instance which is contextually wrong.

Comment: From the second link `By default when a stored procedure is made and the EXECUTE AS option is not used, sql server will execute as the user calling it`  - you can see this easily by making a user `test` which owns cp, and then change your procedure `WITH EXEC AS 'test'`. Then it'll use the cp schema. That an inconsistency exists with tables, does not make this a bug.

Comment: It doesn't make it right either, inconsistency points more to a bug unless there's good reason for it, than design and at the very least something that hasn't been thought through.